# Can't find DefaultBootstrap class in OpenSAML

Tags: java, opensaml, classnotfound

I'm trying to use OpenSAML to establish communication with an IdentityProvider. The thing is I'm following [this](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManJavaSOAPClientExample) example but I can't find the class named DefaultBootstrap.

I'm using Maven to add the dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
  <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
   <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
   <artifactId>openws</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This class is supposed to be in this path:

> org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap

But I can't import it since it doesn't exist (according to eclipse)

Anyone knows why?

Cheer from Chile!

Comment: Guessing this is a geeral dependency problem. Can you get any clases under org.opensaml?

Comment: I actually can use any other class under org.opensaml. Why why this is weird. I Also thought that maybe the issue was with the version i was using, so i tried with other versions, but still can find that class :(

Comment: Can you see org.opensaml.Configuration? and org.opensaml.ESAPISecurityConfig

Comment: I don't, actually I can only see packages at org.opensaml level: http://grab.by/JiSG

Comment: Ok, it looks like you only have the openws imported. if you had the OpenSAML one you should see these packages https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/opensaml/opensaml/2.5.3/opensaml-2.5.3-javadoc.jar/!/index.html

Comment: Have you tried mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate project files?